# Why does $\sqrt{2}+1$ show up here?

Tags: calculus, integration

I was messing around with integrals on Desmos, and I found that for some reason $\sqrt{2}+1$ is the perfect `n` value where $\int_{1}^{n}xdx$ equals `x`, as in it's where $f\left(n\right)=\int_{1}^{n}xdx$ and $y=x$ intersect. I can't, however, figure out why such a neat irrational number would show up in this way.

Comment: It solves $\frac{x^2}2-\frac12=x$. The indefinite integral is $\frac{x^2}2+C$ since $y=x$ form a triangle with the $x$ axis. Then apply the integration bounds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your notation and phrasing is a bit ambiguous, so I'm going to assume this graph below is what you mean to ask about

[image]

We have $$\int_1^x t\text{ d}t=\left.\frac{t^2}{2}\right|^{x}_1=\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac12$$
Set this equal to the identity function we have
$$\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac12=x$$
$$\implies \frac{x^2}{2}-x-\frac12=0$$
$$\implies x=1\pm\sqrt2$$
The two intersections are given by the solutions above
[image]